# how to make null values and empty element in xml have open tags and close tag? Asp.net web api 2

Tags: c#, xml, webapi

i am making a web api and i want to make the open tags and close tags for empty elements and null values. i am using C# and visual basic to code.

My Questions: How to make open tags and close tags for null values and empty elements in xml format with C#?

result outcome:

```
<UserId>32</UserId>
<Name>Emily</Name>
<Mobile>47542942</Mobile>
<Age/>
<Date i:nil="true"/>
<UserId>12</UserId>
<Name>Peter</Name>
<Mobile>102352134</Mobile>
<Age/>
<Date i:nil="true"/>
```

expect result outcome:

```
<UserId>32</UserId>
<Name>Emily</Name>
<Mobile>47542942</Mobile>
<Age></Age>
<Date></Date>
<UserId>12</UserId>
<Name>Peter</Name>
<Mobile>102352134</Mobile>
<Age></Age>
<Date></Date>
```

**OR**

```
<UserId>32</UserId>
<Name>Emily</Name>
<Mobile>47542942</Mobile>
<Age>null</Age>
<Date>null</Date>
<UserId>12</UserId>
<Name>Peter</Name>
<Mobile>102352134</Mobile>
<Age>null</Age>
<Date>null</Date>
```

My code:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAll()
        {
            List<TestClass> draft = new List<TestClass>();
            string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
            string sqlquery = "SELECT UserID, Name, Mobile, Age, Date FROM tblTest";
            sqlconn.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
            SqlDataReader sdr = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                  draft.Add(new TestClass()
                  {
                        UserId = sdr.GetString(0),
                        Name = sdr.GetString(1),
                        Mobile = sdr.GetString(2),
                        Age = (sdr.GetValue(3) != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToInt32(sdr.GetValue(3)) : 0,
                        Date = (sdr.GetValue(4) != DBNull.Value) ? Convert.ToDateTime(sdr.GetValue(4)) : (DateTime)sdr.GetValue(4)
                  });
            }
            return Ok(draft);
        }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: "<Age/>" and "<Age></Age>"are equivalent according to the XML specification.  The tag name in the closing node is optional.  The Net library only outputs "<Age/>" when a node is empty.  So the answer is no in Net libraries but it should not make any difference because the XML meets the XML specification.

Comment: if i don't use net libraries, are there anyways to make it possible?

Comment: Do not know about other libraries.